# C#/ASP.NET MVC3, convert from DateTime.UtcNow, to client's timezone. How to get timezone info?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

I store dates as UTC, by calling DateTime.UtcNow when inserting new records. I want to convert that date to the visitor's timezone.

There's a method on TimeZoneInfo to do it:

```
public static DateTime ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    DateTime dateTime,
    TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone
)
```

but where can I pull `TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone` from, in asp.net mvc3? Is it reliably available in the request object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not as straightforward as one would expect.
The Request object will not give you the info you require.
You will need to use javascript.
Here is a good implementation:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cprieto/archive/2010/01/03/handling-timezone-information-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Well that's not good. Fortunately, for me in this case I can just use ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") and the jQuery TimeAgo plugin takes care of the rest. Thanks for the quick response.