# What is the best way to show LocalTime for a DateTime set to UTC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, utc, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC3 and MongoDB for a web app.  MongoDB uses UTC and the server hosting the app is also using UTC. If I use DateTime.ToLocalTime() in the View that will just return the server's time which is still in UTC.

I would like to display the DateTime objects that a user interacts with in their Local time, does anyone know the best method for achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789679/c-asp-net-mvc3-convert-from-datetime-utcnow-to-clients-timezone-how-to-get-t

Comment: Does not really provide a solution and the one offered is for asp.net not mvc3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess at this [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/df0bdca5cc216311/2f4919ab3c211784?lnk=gst&q=c#%20dates#2f4919ab3c211784) on google groups you should find answer on your question